# Having an object follow a parabolic trajectory in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two points, `A` and `B`. I have an object at point `A` that I want to follow a parabolic trajectory from `A` to the point in the middle of `A` and `B`, at an height of `h`.

I made a picture, I hope it's clear enough:

[image]

Here's what I tried (it's a coroutine):

```
GameObject movingObject = this.movingObject; //this is the object I want to move
Vector3 pointB = target.position
Vector3 pointA = start.position

Vector3 direction = (pointB-pointA).normalized;
Vector3 nextTranslation;
float t, distance, distanceCovered, parameter, speed, startTime;
distance = (targetPosition-startPosition).magnitude; //distance between A and B
distanceCovered = 0; 
p = 1000f; //parameter p for the parabola
speed = 10;
startTime = Time.time;

//travel only half the distance
while (distanceCovered < (distance/2)) {
    t = Time.time - startTime; //elapsed time 

    //I use the parabole parametric equation to determine the next move
    nextTranslation = new Vector3 (direction.x * parameter * t, (parameter/2) * Mathf.Pow(t, 2f), direction.z * parameter * t);
    nextTranslation.Normalize ();

    distanceCovered += speed;
    pawn.transform.Translate(nextTranslation*speed, Space.World);

    yield return null;
}
```

It works, but the parameter `p` doesn't seems to influence the trajectory. I can't influence the height `h` at wich the object will stop, it's alway the same no matter the parameter `p` I use.

Comment: is it because you don't seem to be using p anywhere? I am looking inside the while and do not see any iteration of it. If so, get ready for face-palm :).

Comment: Maybe `p` should be `parameter`?

Comment: No it's not that, the parameter was a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: Why not just give it a Rigidbody component and set its initial velocity?